# Entity Framework: how to set the type of a column as uniqueidentifier with Fluent API

Tags: entity-framework-6, azure-mobile-services, uniqueidentifier, ef-fluent-api, ef-code-first-mapping

I use Entity Framework 6, code-first.

I have a column `<string> Id` that is created by a framework (Azure Mobile Server SDK), which I don't have access to.

```
public abstract class EntityData
{
    [Key]
    [TableColumn(TableColumnType.Id)]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

If I don't perform any action, such column is mapped as a `nvarchar(MAX)` in SQL Server.

I have been able to turn it into a `char(36)` with this snippet in Fluent API:

```
PropertyConventionConfiguration pkConf = modelBuilder.Properties<string>().Where(p => p.Name == "Id");
pkConf.Configure(p => p.IsUnicode(false));
pkConf.Configure(p => p.HasMaxLength(36));
pkConf.Configure(p => p.IsFixedLength());
```

I want to set it as `uniqueidentifier`.

How can I do that with a similar Fluent API code snippet?

Thank you very much!

Comment: What happens if you change Id to be of type Guid instead of string? You will obviously need to remove to length constraint. Guid should map to uniqueidentifier.

Comment: I cannot touch the class definition since it is in the Azure SDK, not my code

Comment: Posted response as an answer below.

Comment: Did this solve your problem?

Comment: @MehdiIbrahim Please check my comments on your answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a custom value converter or leverage the built in **GuidToStringConverter** : [learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions](http://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions) . A few side notes - you should create a class that inherits from this abstract class. This not only offers a layer of abstraction, it will also allow you to control more precisely how you store and access your data. Also, as you're probably aware, GUIDs make horrible PKs!

**EDIT:**

If you're using EF 6, this feature won't be available. You will therefore, need to create a wrapper property or use a stored procedure. Here's an example, sample code can be found here: https://github.com/ibrahm2/entityframework6-map-string-to-guid

**Method 1: Wrapper Property**

1. Create a class that inherits from `EntityData`. For this example, let's call it `WrapperTable` e.g.
2. Add a property called `Id` with type `Guid` and mask the base `Id` property by using the `new` modifier. Have it return a cast version of `Id` from the base class as `Guid`. This will mask the base property. It isn't best practice so if you're uncomfortable with this, the alternative would be to create a new property e.g. called `Key` that wraps around `Id`.
3. If your configuration, map the inherited class to the `EntityDate` table.

   modelBuilder.Entity().ToTable("EntityData");

**Method 2: Stored Procedure**

1. Create a stored procedure that takes in a varchar as a parameter for the Id field
2. Map the stored procedure to the Insert function of the Entity e.g.:

   modelBuilder.Entity().MapToStoredProcedures(prop=>prop.Insert(sp=>sp.HasName("sp_InsertTable").Parameter(pm => pm.Id, "@id")));
3. Have the stored procedure insert the varchar into your uniqueidentifier field.

Comment: Hi @MehdiIbrahim, thanks for the proposal, but I have few problems:1) I want to change from String to Guid, not from Guid to String! 2) the value conversion is persent in EF Core, where I can use only the "normal" EF 6

Comment: Updated my answer. Sorry, I don't think have you any cleaner options with EF6.

Comment: BTW, have you tried pkConf.Configure(p => p.HasColumnType("uniqueidentifier")); ?

Comment: Thank you @MehdiIbrahim for the proposal, unfortunately it gives me this problem: [error 2019: Member Mapping specified is not valid. The type 'Edm.String[Nullable=False,DefaultValue=,MaxLength=36,Unicode=False,FixedLength=True]' of member 'Id' in type 'LTSyncMobile.Models.TodoItem' is not compatible with 'SqlServer.uniqueidentifier[Nullable=False,DefaultValue=]' of member 'Id' in type 'CodeFirstDatabaseSchema.TodoItem'.]

Comment: Another idea is to map your insert function to a stored procedure. Please review revised answer. I created some sample code for you and tried both methods and verified them as working. https://github.com/ibrahm2/entityframework6-map-string-to-guid

Comment: Hey Mehdi, it seems the creation of a *new* Id property is doing the trick, but this requires me a substantial amount of changes. I am still in the process of covering all the holes... I will let you know. In the meantime... THANKS!!

Comment: Excellent, glad I was able to help - even if only a bit. Please accept the answer and upvote if you're satisfied.

Comment: Hi Mehdi, I am now stuck on a further problem that has been introduced by this change: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52122937/c-sharp-odata-cannot-build-an-system-web-http-odata-delta-using-a-type-with-a. I cannot bless the change until I don't find a solution for this problem :(

Comment: That's a separate problem and should be a separate question. I don't think anybody over here is going to be motivated to help out infinitely on every single issue you're running into - related or unrelated without acknowledgement that you've received two solutions to your original problem. I'm 100% sure though that my answer here - both options - will be extremely valuable to others out there running into similar problems. Good luck!

Comment: Hey Medhi, actually I agree with your approach, you're right, from an SO point of view the answer is complete. Thank you again for yorr support!

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at your new issue in a bit.

Comment: Thank you very much, that would be fantastic! I posted an SO question, if you want to take a look (check the previous comment)

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<TodoItem>().Property(t => t.Id).HasColumnType("UniqueIdentifier");
```

More information for your reference:

[Configuring the Data Type of a Database Column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/fluent/types-and-properties#configuring-the-data-type-of-a-database-column)

Comment: Hi Lee, thanks for the proposal, unfortunately it gives me this problem: [error 2019: Member Mapping specified is not valid. The type 'Edm.String[Nullable=False,DefaultValue=,MaxLength=36,Unicode=False,FixedLength=True]' of member 'Id' in type 'LTSyncMobile.Models.TodoItem' is not compatible with 'SqlServer.uniqueidentifier[Nullable=False,DefaultValue=]' of member 'Id' in type 'CodeFirstDatabaseSchema.TodoItem'.]